# jQuery Tiny Scrollbar plugin - Fails to show all content on refresh

Tags: jquery, scrollbar, page-refresh

I've implemented Tiny Scrollbar plugin on a website, for good-looking div scrolling. But weird stuff happens when I refresh the page in Safari or Chrome. It seams to clip some of my content. What happens upon a page refresh, that could make it behave like this?
Please have a look at [mettestentoft.dk](http://mettestentoft.dk/erhverv.html)

I've tried using the same plugin on a simple test page, where a page refresh would make the plugin add a 'scrollbar disable' class to the div, while clicking a link linking to the same page, would make i show as it should.

Tiny Scrollbar plugin demopage doesn't seem to have any problems, unless I'm missing it.

So my question is: Do I have to do something jQuery-wise, in order for a page to load equally to a linked page?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you initializing the Scrollbar plugin?  is it `$('#cases_container').tinyscrollbar();`?

Remove the set height of the `#cases_container` div.

Nodo.css line: 101.

```
#cases_container {
    /*height: 383px;*/
    width: 550px;
    /*overflow-x: hidden;*/
    /*overflow-y: hidden;*/
    /*position: relative;*/
    /*top: -200px;*/
    /*left: 250px;*/
}
```

I'm assuming doing this will screw up it positioning on the page so create another container div that applys all the relative positions etc. but leave the overflow hidden out of it.

Comment: It sure does screw up the relative positions, but it don't fix the issue. Maybe trouble shooting would be easier on the simple test i did: http://mettestentoft.dk/test/test_erhverv.html . Yes, $('#cases_container').tinyscrollbar(); initializes the scrollbar plugin.

Comment: whatever you just did fixed it for me (chrome 5).
Nevermind the scroll bar works for some reason when i click a link and use the back button.  I would suggest cleaning up the div structure with cleaner wrapper etc instead of all the negative margins and top/left declarations and then trying to add the scroll bar.

Comment: Do you end up with a scrollbar when you refresh the page?

Comment: Not on a refresh, but for some reason when I go to another page and use browser back button it adjusts correctly.  I have no idea why.  All the css looks exactly the same which leads me to think its a problem with loading the scrollbar plugin before some img is loaded into the div.

AHH! Load the scrollbar javascript just before the end of the body tag. Bingo

Comment: Cha-ching! Thanks a bunch Cole! You brought Christmas early to me.. now i can get my client off my back for the holidays :D

Answer (score 7):

I tried your code to put js before ending the body tag. I worked for me on local machine or local host but could not solved online.

Then I found ostrgard's website reference: http://mettestentoft.dk/erhverv.html

He has solved that issue. I saw and inspected his code and found the solution there.

Just put this code to work perfect:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).bind("load", function() {     
    $('#scrollbar1').tinyscrollbar();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, shahzad's solution did work for me, but only on first load, never on refresh. This was caused by jQuery load cache. Solution:

```
$(window).load({noncache: new Date().getTime()},function() { $('#scrollbar1').tinyscrollbar();} );
```