# Fancy Box and Jquery Tiny Scroll Bar Prolem

Tags: php, jquery, fancybox

I am working on a page and having problem with the Fancybox close action for the Image gallery in the first button at the bottom, the gallery is closed but overaly is still there. [Here](http://www.providentfeed.com/beta/psale_detail.php?pid=6579) is the test link 
How ever the same settings are working for the second link "Floor Plan".

Secondly I am using a Tiny Scrollbar plugin for the gallery on the page. The thumbs on the left side have blue scroll bar if they are larger in contents. This scroll bar does not appear in Google Chrome, and sometime don't show up even in other browser if the page loads first time, then I have to refresh the page to show it. Any idea about the problem will be greatly helpful.

Thank you!

Comment: Not seeing your tiny-scrollbars anywhere. Is that the problem?

Comment: Yes, at first it does not show up, and when I refresh the page second time, it appears.

Comment: I'll edit my answer to include the scrollbar fix too, wait a sec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, I noticed you're suing jQuery 1.3, why?
Here's 1.6:
http://jquery.com/

It isn't that much larger, and its an updated library. That may fix your problem.

If that didn't work, then delete the fancybox.js, re-downlod and put it in again, same with css. Make sure the css is called at the end of your css document.

If that doesn't work, I suggest getting rid of your javascript files one by one until there is only fnaycbo xleft, it's obviously some conflicting code at this point, so you'll have to troubleshoot by trial and error, going through one by one to findout what script is preventing close. I don't have access to your server, so I can't test it.

It's most likely in main.js, so remove that first, and see if fancybox works then!

ETA: Scrollbar fix.

The problem is something is adding a disabled selector, it's javascript. But you could change up tinyscrollbar.js to fix it, or you could go to your css, find the line:

'#scrollbar1 .disable {display:none}

and remove that line entirley, it's causing your scrollbar not to appear in browsers the javascript is (for some reason) disabling in.

Comment: Thank you Jackson Gariety,Fancy Box gallery is working fine now. But still I have the problem with scrollbar.

Comment: Maybe you wouldn't mind givin' me a little vote-up. ^_^
But, how are you using the plugin, you said on the gallery, I don't se any custom scrollbars on the gallery. :/

Comment: Found it,
in your main.css,
the line
'#scrollbar1 disable{display:none}'
Take out that line

Comment: Jackson I was not able to find that line in my CSS file(mainStyleSheet.css). Can you please point out the file, line number? thank you!

Comment: It's line 315 of mainstylesheet.css
#scrollbar1 .disable { display: none; }
that['s the line exactly
It's headed "/**************** Tiny Scrollbar ************/"

Comment: Yes, Jackson, man you rocks, you have solved my problem. Thank you :)

Comment: :D
I just love to be involved in the design community. I'm a a freshman in highschool using this site to learn more about the world of web design, so it was my pleasure. ;)

Answer (score 2):

In my case I solved with the next modification:

```
$(document).bind("load", function() { $('#myTinyScrollbar').tinyscrollbar(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you have an error in console:

> d.onClosed is not a function

It could be because:

- Your using an **old version of jQuery** possibly not supported by Fancybox. Try updating to 1.6, though beware legacy plugins or code that could break due to the steep upgrade.
- **A compression issue.** It's possible i.e. the Google Closure could of removed what it saw as "unneeded" code and therefore broke the functionality. Try using uncompressed Fancybox to see if it fixes it, if it does then you know this the issue, rather than your jQuery version.

Comment: Yes Gary thank you for your reply, I updated the Jquery version and Fancy Box gallery is working fine now. But the still I have the problem with scrollbar. Any idea please?

Comment: I fixed the Tiny Scroll Bar PLugin problem by adding this one after body tag. <code>$(window).bind("load", function() { $('#scrollbar1').tinyscrollbar(); });</code> and I found this solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4513128/jquery-tiny-scrollbar-plugin-fails-to-show-all-content-on-refresh